# Не работает zip_longest из itertools python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.x

разъясните пожалуйста понять почему у меня не работает zip_longest?
вроде бы как должен быть в пакете itertools, но при попытке использования в таком виде:

```
import itertools
z = izip_longest(list_name,param1)
```

получаю ошибку:

```
 z = izip_longest(list_name,param1)
NameError: name 'izip_longest' is not defined
```

если использовать вот так:

```
z = itertools.izip_longest(list_name,param1)
```

получаю:

```
<itertools.izip_longest object at 0x03128C60>
```

при этом zip работает без проблем.

PS.менять версию Python 2.7 на более свежую недопустимо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давайте по порядку:

```py
import itertools
z = izip_longest(list_name,param1)
```

не работает потому, что вы импортируете модуль целиком а не имя `izip_longest` из него.

Правильно так:

```py
from itertools import izip_longest
z = izip_longest(list_name,param1)
```

или так

```py
import itertools
z = itertools.izip_longest(list_name,param1)
```

Что подводит нас ко второму вопросу: `z = itertools.izip_longest(list_name,param1)` это правильный способ использования `izip_longest`

Результат, который вы получаете - не список, а ленивый генератор, как и в случае использования других функций с префиксом `i`: `izip`, `imap`, `ifilter`, `ifilterfalse`.

В последующих версиях python они полностью заменили соответствующие функции, возвращающие список - `zip`, `map`, `filter` взяв их имена.

Если вам в качестве результата нужен именно список, оберните результат выполнения `izip_longest` в `list`

```py
z = list(itertools.izip_longest(list_name,param1))
```

Если же вам просто нужно последовательно проитерировать пары элементов списков, в ряде случаев выгоднее будет просто использовать результат `izip_longest` в качестве аргумента цикла `for`

```py
for x, y in itertools.izip_longest(list_name,param1):
    print(x, y)
```

или в качестве аргумента генераторного выражения

```py
result = sum(x for x, y in itertools.izip_longest(list_name,param1) if y)
```

или передать его в функцию, готовую работать с любым итерируемым типом, а не только со списком (таких большинство)

```py
result = max(itertools.izip_longest(list_name,param1))
```

```py
result = dict(itertools.izip_longest(list_name,param1))
```

Answer (score 4):

Во-первых, чтобы использовать имя функции без имени пакета, нужно импортировать её в пространство имён текущего модуля

```
from itertools import izip_longest
```

Во-вторых, `izip_longest` возвращает итератор. Чтобы получить его значение, его надо *вычислить*

```
print(list(z))
```

**P.S.** Уже через 5 месяцев Python 2.7 и все ориентированные на него библиотеки перестанут получать обновления. Недопустимо продолжать его использовать.